# Is it possible to push changes into a branch which is already merged in Gerrit

Tags: ios, reactjs, git, react-native, gerrit

I have a branch named **bugs_feature** which i have already merged into develop branch. Next time when i work on the same branch which has fix for some other bug, Can i push that fix for code review to same branch **bugs_feature** which is already in merged state.

I have tried with below commands, but it din't work

```
      xxxx@xxxx-MacBook-Pro SampleApp % git commit -m "Fixed issue HRODS-945"
   [bugfix_dashboard 226f6b6] Fixed issue HRODS-945
    5 files changed, 78 insertions(+), 45 deletions(-)
   xxxx@xxxx-MacBook-Pro SampleApp % git push 
   "https://xxxx@reviewba.xxxxx.com:8459/a/Sample/Sample-mobile-app" 
   HEAD:refs/for/bugfix_dashboard

   Counting objects: 34, done.
   Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (34/34), 4.43 KiB | 1.48 MiB/s, done.
   Total 34 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)
   remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (19/19)
   remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
   To https://reviewba.xxxx.com:8459/a/Sample/sample-mobile-app
   ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/bugfix_dashboard (change 
   https://reviewba.xxxxx.com:8459/c/Sample/sample-mobile-app/+/185 closed)
   error: failed to push some refs to 
  'https://xxxxxx@reviewba.xxxxx.com:8459/a/Sample/sample-mobile-app'
```

Even tried with git commit --amend and modified the changed Id, so gerrit might consider it as a new push for code review.

Is it because the branch is already in merged i'm not able to push or Gerrit doesn't support pushing code to a already merged branch.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message says that change 185 is closed (you can't push to a closed change). Please show the error message when you have used a different Change-Id. BTW, in the text you mentioned that you have used a branch called "bugs_feature", but in the error message the branch is called "bugfix_dashboard", is this correct?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira Sorry for the late response, just for understading purpose i have written as bugs_feature, but actually my branch name is bugfix_dashboard. I think the message was same even when i tried with different changed ID. Do we need to completely change the Change ID or just add some random numbers at the last of existing change ID.? Thank you.

Comment: You just need to REPLACE some random numbers. If you change the Change ID it should create a new change and no error is expected to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me after following the hint from the git command prompt message.

```
  remote: ERROR: commit ac81273: invalid Change-Id line format in message footer
  remote: 
  remote: Hint: run
  remote:   git commit --amend
  remote: and move 'Change-Id: Ixxx..' to the bottom on a separate line
  remote:
```

Step 1 : After using the git commit -amend

when you enter into the edit format of the earlier commit message screen.

Step 2 :Go to line of the Change ID and move it to couples of lines down and on Top

Step 3 :Type **Change Id: "your commit Id goes here"**(should be like the below format).

- It starts with an uppercase I;
- It contains 32 hexadecimal characters;

One sample format could be :

```
I201611160832aa0000000000786176696572
```

It starts with the date and time (YYYYMMDDHHMM), followed by a separator, and then the name of the committer in hexa format (here i used ascii, but one could use another format), padded with 00.